# Material Favorite Button vs Image Button

Tags: android, button

What is the difference between MaterialFavoriteButton and image button? As both are buttons are same why image button can't be used as Favorite button?

Comment: Which "MaterialFavoriteButton"? Are you referring to https://github.com/IvBaranov/MaterialFavoriteButton?

Comment: Yes I am referring that MaterialFavoriteButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are welcome to use `ImageView` or `ImageButton` for a favorite button. `MaterialFavoriteButton` has additional features that some developers may like:

- The ability to provide the favorite and not-favorite images as simple drawable resources, or opt into built-in star or heart images if they fit your needs
- Integrated animations for transitioning between those images
- Simple event handlers for finding out when the user toggles the state and when the animations end

If you do not want those features, or you do not want to use open source libraries, you do not need to use `MaterialFavoriteButton`.